# Dojo NumberTextBox : defining max constraint

Tags: dojo, constraints, max, dijit.form

I'm having troubles with the NumberTextBox max constraint. If I use standard markup declaration and create the numbertextbox with default setting, e.g.

```js
dojo.require("dijit.form.NumberTextBox");
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">
<input id="q05" type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.NumberTextBox" constraints="{places:0}" required="true" >
```

this control is constrained to be max of 16digits. And that's the issue. What if I need the user to be able to enter a 16+ digit number?
I seem to be unable to overwrite this with the constraints:"{max:99999999999999999999}" (it's 20 of them) nor with the maxLength:"20" attributes.

Any ideas on how to properly set the control to be constrained let's say up to 20 digits, instead of 16 (which appears to be a limit now)?

Thank you

Comment: With the floating point implementation in Javascript, you're not going to get precision on that many digits.  The widget isn't tested with numbers that large, which I think used to have round-tripping problems, but it looks like you should be able to set max to anything you want.  _setConstraintsAttr only uses 9*10^(15-p) by default?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ValidationTextBox` and use propert `regExp` to narrow possible input.